# DoS: how to limit access to /dev/random?

Tags: devices

One of my users likes to `cat /dev/random > /dev/null`. This has caused issues with other processes performing poorly because they're blocked waiting for entropy.

Is there a way of preventing users from consuming too much randomness?

I've tried `cat /dev/zero > /dev/random` but of course that doesn't increase the entropy count.

Comment: Do you know why is this user doing this?

Comment: If the user is doing this to cause a DoS, they are probably breaking the usage agreement for using the system and should have their account suspended.  This is an issue that is better solved in dialogue than with some form of technical hack.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/379914/centos-pxe-anaconda-kickstart-waiting-to-gather-enough-entropy/380034#380034

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro You've linked to an answer about increasing the amount of entropy. The title of my question is how to impose quotas on lusers. These are not the same.

Comment: @user234461 Indeed, that is why I left it as a commend, and not as a VTC. But be aware entropy is limited in some settings.

Comment: `mount --bind /dev/urandom /dev/random` and your user will generate instead of consuming entropy, and your programs won't block anymore.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out the problem can be solved using the following one-liner:

```
yes | userdel -Z -r -f $(lsof|awk '/\/dev\/random/{print $3}'|head -n1)
```

Comment: Well, if forceful removal of user that is *currently* using `/dev/random` is the correct solution then yes, this one-liner might do it.

Comment: Yikes! BOFH much? What could possibly go wrong...

Comment: @markgraf LOL `chsh -s /bin/bash 7</dev/random` and Bob's your uncle (but only if the OP fixes the quoting in their awk command ;-))

Comment: @mosvy: what does `7</dev/random` do here?

Comment: It redirects fd 7 from `/dev/random`, which fd will be inherited by the `chsh` _setuid_ binary which, while "sleeping as root" waiting for the user to enter the password, will appear in the OP's `lsof` output, and cause the OP's command to remove the root user.

Comment: @mosvy: I don't understand how will `chsh` wait for user to enter the password? It has setuid root set and does not ask for user's password, at least on my Slackware system without PAM.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk you'll have to adapt it then: call it without the `-s` option, with a `-s` option different from the current shell, etc. Or find another setuid binary (eg. `su 7</dev/random`).